# Color cells with specific character values in r to export to xlsx

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to accomplish something that shouldn't be that difficult, yet it escapes my attempts.

So I have an R `Data Frame` (df) which looks something like this:

```
df

MeanTemperature(ºC) Longitude Latitude Height  FinalConsiderations
5                   91ºW      152ºS    548m    Slightly Cooler
16                  185ºE     53ºN     722m    Unchanged
22                  16ºW      2ºS      206m    Significantly Warmer
```

The dataframe is a result of a filtered analyzed data. The end product is an Excel `(xlsx)` where the final column is the conclusion of the overall analysis. So, those steps are all taken care of, but these tables are rather large, so it would be nice to be able to color, for example, in **RED** where it says `"Significantly Warmer"`.

I've tried using the workbook from said dataframe

```
  wb <- loadWorkbook(file) #where file is the location path
```

Here I want to collect those cells where it reads 'Significantly Warmer' in red, and afterwards export the workbook to xlsx.

```
 fo1 <- Fill(foregroundColor="red")    # create fill object # 1
 cs1 <- CellStyle(wb, fill=fo1)        # create cell style # 1
 sheets <- getSheets(wb)               # get all sheets
```

But now I can't find a way of making a function in the wb setting where at the column

`$FinalConsiderations == 'Slightly Cooler'`, the cells foreground is colored red, afterwards exporting to xlsx.

Comment: Have you tried `conditionalFormatting` in `openxlsx` package?

Comment: Well, thanks very much! I looked it up and managed to solve it, I will post how I ended up doing it in case it helps anyone with a similar question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I'll write how I solved it, in case it helps anyone with a similar situation.

I downloaded the `openxlsx` package.

```
library(openxlsx) #recall the library

wb <- createWorkbook() # create a workbook

addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet", gridLines = TRUE) #add a worksheet to the workbook

writeData(wb, "Sheet", df) # write my analysis into the worksheet of the workbook, 
 #where df is the name of my data frame
```

Afterwards, I create the styles, following the `createStyle` function (see documentation).

In my case, I had to look for specific characters in my data

```
 warm1Style <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", bgFill = "#FFFF00")
 # here search for the respective HEX color-code and assign a name to the style

 conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet", cols = 1:ncol(df),
                  rows = 1:nrow(df), rule = "Significantly Warmer", style = warm1Style,
                  type = "contains")
# account the condition where "Significantly Warmer" is contained in a cell,
# then apply the respective style to it (in this case, warm1Style)
```

Then that's it, like so it can be done to any phrase or characters in the workbook.

Finally, save the workbook as an xlsx:

```
saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: This worked great!

Quick note if anyone wants it to apply to your whole data frame, change:

cols=ncol(df) ,rows = 1:nrow(df)

Comment: Many thanks for sharing. Any idea whether there is a package which allows to format individual words within a text cell (not all words in the cell)?

Comment: @zoowalk, isn't `type = 'contains'` what you are looking for?