# How do I format an entire row within xlsx based on a cell character in R

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, openxlsx, r-xlsx

I am using R to edit an xlsx worksheet. I would like to format the worksheet with colored rows based on character values in a specific column, then save the workbook in xlsx form. I successfully loaded the workbook using xlsx in R. I can run through the characters in the workbook and change that specific cell background color based on a condition, but am having trouble changing the color of that entire row.

My question is, how can I make the entire row a solid color, rather than just the cell? So far, I have followed the instructions and code located here:

[Color cells with specific character values in r to export to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213550/color-cells-with-specific-character-values-in-r-to-export-to-xlsx/56873888#56873888)

What would you have to add to the code in the above link to make the entire row the same color as the specific cell that was targeted?

```
greenStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", bgFill = "green")
yellowStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", bgFill = "yellow")
conditionalFormatting(wb, "entire report", cols=1:12, rows=1:2000, rule="Finished", style = greenStyle, type = "contains")
conditionalFormatting(wb, "entire report", cols=1:12, rows=1:2000, rule="In Process", style = yellowStyle, type = "contains")
saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

This question is from some time ago, I was looking to do this, then found the answer and wanted to share (I am the author of the post referred in the question btw :) )

So, in order to color an entire row, I made a reproducible example:

Reproducible example:

```
dfX <- data.frame('a' = c(1:4),
       'b' = c(1:2,2:1),
       'c' = LETTERS[1:4],
       'e' = LETTERS[1:2][2:1],
       'f' = c('Finished', 'In Process', 'In Process', 'In Process'))

library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet", gridLines = TRUE)
writeData(wb, "Sheet", dfX)

greenRows = data.frame(which(dfX == "Finished", arr.ind=TRUE))
yellowRows = data.frame(which(dfX == "In Process", arr.ind=TRUE))
## Here I create data frames where it states which rows and columns
## have 'Finished' and which have 'In Process'. From here I want to keep only the
## rows from these data frames.

# Create a heading style
Heading <- createStyle(textDecoration = "bold", border = "Bottom")

# Row styles
greenStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", fgFill = "green")
yellowStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", fgFill = "yellow")
```

Important Note: I use `"fgFill"` instead of `"bgFill"` because in order to do this, we will use `addStyle` (and not `conditionalFormatting`), and in the documentation, it states that `bgFill` is only for `conditionalFormatting`

```
# Apply header style:
addStyle(wb, "Sheet", cols = 1:ncol(dfX), rows = 1, style = Heading)

# Apply greenStyle:
addStyle(wb, "Sheet", cols = 1:ncol(dfX), rows = greenRows[,1]+1,
         style = greenStyle, gridExpand = TRUE)

# Apply yellowStyle:
addStyle(wb, "Sheet", cols = 1:ncol(dfX), rows = yellowRows[,1]+1,
         style = yellowStyle, gridExpand = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite=TRUE)
```

Note that in `"rows = "` I input `greenRows[,1]+1`, which means only the first column of the greenRows data.frame, plus 1 (the first row would be the header, so skip this one)

Also note that in the last line, in the `file` part you should specify the directory where to save the file with the `.xlsx` termination, such as:

```
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "C:/Documents/newfile.xlsx", overwrite=TRUE)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244303/multiple-styles-applied-to-the-same-row-with-package-openxlsx), though not the same question, helped me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example! I'm trying to implement it now. I'm hitting a roadblock here: 

Error in "Style" %in% class(style) : object 'duppedStyle' not found

Any thoughts?

Comment: silly me, I copied wrong one step, there I corrected it in the answer. The problem was in the `addStyle` part, where it says `style` I should put the style names previously defined (`greenStyle` and `yellowStyle` respectively)